# problema com random.radint(1, 6) e condicional if

Tags: python, if, random, else

Amigos, estou começando na programação, assim me desculpo se for muito banal minha questão.
Meu palpite é que algo acontece na string if, porque nunca a mensagem de vitória é lida, o programa sempre lê o "Try Again', e isso mesmo se acerto o número.

Alguém poderia lançar uma luz por favor?

```
import random

dada = random.randint(1, 6)

guess = input('Make a choice between the numbers: 1 and 6: ')

if dada == guess:
    print('Congratulations! You won!')
else:
    print('Try again.')

print('You selected the number {} and the number {} was sorted.'.format(guess, dada))

print("Let's play again!")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Victor,

Isso está acontecendo por conta dos tipos de variáveis.

Sua variável `dada` é um *inteiro* (int), retorno do método randint, porém a variável `guess` é uma *string* (str), pois a função input retorna um texto.

Para corrigir essa situação, você pode converter o retorno da função input para um inteiro, com a função int, exemplo:

```
guess = int(input('Make a choice between the numbers: 1 and 6: '))
```

Portanto seu código, ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
import random

dada = random.randint(1, 6)

guess = int(input('Make a choice between the numbers: 1 and 6: '))

if dada == guess:
    print('Congratulations! You won!')
else:
    print('Try again.')

print('You selected the number {} and the number {} was sorted.'.format(guess, dada))

print("Let's play again!")
```

Comment: Obrigado Daniel Mendes, com certeza ajudou. Fique louco com isso aqui desde ontem, mas que erro bobo. Mas bem, acho que é assim mesmo no começo. Novamente obrigado.